# 2 counters not appearing at the same time in android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and java and im trying my best to do a simple game called rockpaper scissor.

I am wondering why does my code `cScore = 0;` wont appear at the same time with `yScore=0`. I need to press again the rock button to reset the `cScore` back to 0.
Please help, any kind of suggestions will do.
thanks.

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView youOutput, compOutput, youScore, compScore;
        int yScore=0, cScore=0, cPicked;
        Random abc = new Random();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    youOutput =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.youOutput);
    compOutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.compOutput);
    youScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.youScore);
    compScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.compScore);
}

public void rockButton(View view) {

    youOutput.setText("Rock");
    cPicked = 1+abc.nextInt(3);


    if (cPicked == 1) {
        compOutput.setText("Rock");
        compScore.setText(Integer.toString(cScore));
        youScore.setText(Integer.toString(yScore));
    } else if(cPicked == 2) {
        compOutput.setText("Paper");
        cScore++;

            if(cScore == 10){
                cScore = 0;
                yScore = 0;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Computer won", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else
        compScore.setText(Integer.toString(cScore));
        youScore.setText(Integer.toString(yScore));
    } else {
        compOutput.setText("Scissor");
        yScore++;
        if(yScore == 10){
            cScore = 0;
            yScore = 0;
            Toast.makeText(this, "You won", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else
        compScore.setText(Integer.toString(cScore));
        youScore.setText(Integer.toString(yScore));
    }

}
```

Comment: the sooner you get rid of bad habit of not putting conditional blocks (esp. oneliners) in `{` `}`, the better for you.

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to use the debugger that is part of Android Studio. This is an indispensable tool for every Android programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Add curly brackets in last else block and else block in if (cPicked == 2)

```
  if (cPicked == 1) {
        compOutput.setText("Rock");
        compScore.setText(Integer.toString(cScore));
        youScore.setText(Integer.toString(yScore));
    } else if (cPicked == 2) {
        compOutput.setText("Paper");
        cScore++;

        if (cScore == 10) {
            cScore = 0;
            yScore = 0;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Computer won", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //added curly brackets
        } else {
            compScore.setText(Integer.toString(cScore));
            youScore.setText(Integer.toString(yScore));
        }
    } else {
        compOutput.setText("Scissor");
        yScore++;
        if (yScore == 10) {
            cScore = 0;
            yScore = 0;
            Toast.makeText(this, "You won", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          //added curly brackets
        } else {
            compScore.setText(Integer.toString(cScore));
            youScore.setText(Integer.toString(yScore));
        }
    }
```